# passing an interface from class to synchronous service

Tags: java, android

Sorry to ask an old question. but I think my problem is other as I'm trying to pass an `interface` from a class to synchronize service, I'm able to fetch some parameters value but some of parameters value showing null. May be this is an old question but I didn't find anything related to my problem. Thanks in advance  code is-

```
Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SyncService.class);

i.putExtra("insight", (Parcelable) interface);

mContext.startService(i);

public static class SyncService extends
            SynchronousIntentService
interface= intent.getExtras().getParcelable("interface");
```

Comment: Hey ankit, your question is so flue that it is hard to understand what exactly your are trying to ask. Can you provide some code fraction etc.

Comment: I am sending the interface by intent to syncservice.class from a activity.and I am unable to get data here.